# No funciona metodo hover con jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

intento explicar el problema, tengo un pequeño juego de ordenar letras (trabajo escolar), con jquery ui que permita arrastrar bloques y ordenarlos en la secuencia correcta, estando el contenido como oculto, con una clase.

Pues bien, resulta que quiero implementar que al terminar de arrastrar el bloque al pasar el ratón por encima se muestre la etiqueta del bloque eliminado la clase que lo oculta con CSS, pero no me funciona.

He probado utilizar JS Nativo, pero tampoco me funciona, parece que el problema es al definir el tipo de bloque con jqueryUI, ya que dejan de funcionar los eventos, como click, hover, moouse enter...

Pongo el código por si alguien puede ayudarme. Un millón de gracias.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   
   //Metodo que intenta ocultar la clase oculto y mostrar el contenido
   
    $( ".oculto" ).on( "hover", function() {
        $( ".oculto" ).removeClass( "newClass", 'no');
        document.getElementsByClassName("oculto")[1].classList.remove("oculto");
      });
    


    var sort1 = $("#notSelected").sortable({

        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    var sort2 = $("#Selected").sortable({

        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    var contador = 1;

    $("form").on('click', function () {
        var notSelected = [];
        var Selected = [];

        $("#notSelected li").each(function (idx) {
            notSelected.push($(this).text());

        });
        // console.log("Los elementos no seleccionados son: " + notSelected);

        $("#Selected li").each(function (idx) {
            Selected.push($(this).text());
            // $('.oculto').removeClass();
        });
      

       

      $("#oculto").hover(function(){
        alert("ey")
    }, function(){
       alert("eo")
    });

        $("ul li span").on("hover", function () {
            $('.oculto').removeClass("oculto","no");
            $(".oculto").removeClass("newClass", 1000, callback);
            $('ul:eq(0) li').removeClass();
            console.log("hola")
        });


        // console.log("La secuencia es: " + Selected[0]);
        if (Selected.length == 5) {
            var ok = true
            var correcto = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
            for (let index = 0; index < Selected.length; index++) {
                if (Selected[index] != correcto[index]) {
                    ok = false;


                    // Selected[index] != correcto[index] ? console.log('ok') : console.log("no correcto");
                }


            }
            console.log(ok);
            ok ? alert("Ha ganado") + $('#mensaje').append("Has Ganado") : alert("sigue jugando");
            $('.general').append('<br> Partida' + contador + ': ' + Selected + '<br>')
            $('.oculto').removeClass();
            contador++;
            if (ok != 'ganado') {

                $('#reiniciar').click(function () {
                    // $('.connectedSortable').addClass('.sortable notSelected');
                    $('ul:eq(0) li').remove();
                    $('ul:eq(0)').append('<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">a</span></li> <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">e</span></li> <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">i</span></li><li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">o</span></li><li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">u</span></li>')
                    $('ul:eq(1) li').remove();
                    $('#mensaje').text = 'hola';
                    //$(this).off();
                    // alert("ha reiniciado")
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("No ha introducido todas las vocales")
        }
    })

});
```

```css
        body {
            background-color: grey;
        }

        .sortable {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 550px;
        }

        .sortable li {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
            padding: 1px;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 90px;
            font-size: 4em;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        .oculto {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #notSelected,
        #Selected,
        .general {
            border: 1px, solid #eee;
            width: 442px;
            min-height: 72px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 0 0 0;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        #notSelect li,
        #Selected li {
            margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            width: 120px;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
            padding: 1px;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 90px;
            font-size: 4em;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        .ayuda {
            margin-left: 560px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
 
</head>

<body>
  
    <form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <h1 id='mensaje'></h1>

        <h3 class="general"> Ordena las vocales en orden alfabético</h3>

        <br style="clear:both">

        <h3>Vocales</h3>
        <h3 class="ayuda"> Coloque aqui su elección:</h3>

        <ul id="notSelected" class="sortable notSelected">
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">a</span></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">

            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">e</span></li>

            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">o</span></li>

            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="oculto">u</span></li>

        </ul>
        <div style="width:2px;height:200px;
        right: 200px;
        float: left;
        border-right:2px solid black;
        padding-left:20px;margin-left:20px;
        margin: 20px;
        "></div>

        <ul id="Selected" class="connectedSortable">

        </ul>
        <p></p>
        <button class="Selected" type="button" id="push">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="reiniciar">Nueva partida</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 errores graves para lo que buscas,

1.- un elemento con **visibility: hidden** no es objeto del foco, por ende, nunca sucede el hover, en su lugar utiliza **opacity: 0**

2.- el evento hover de jquery es

```
$('.oculto').hover(function(){...})
```

Si son elementos cargados por ajax

```
$('.oculto').on('mouseover', function(){...})
```